# How to add a SAML external identity provider to azure active directory?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have an Single Page Application that needs to authenticate against Azure Active Directory with OAuth.

I want the authentication to be done using AD accounts, or different external data providers like Google, Facebook, and... one that is based on SAML.

How can I integrate a SAML external identity provider into Azure AD?

**NB: The question is not** *"how to use Azure AD as a SAML identity provider?"*

Comment: Did my answer solve your issue?

Comment: I need to try it out, as I still need to have the saml dataprovider to work properly, I can't test right now. Don't worry, I will mark your answer as correct if it works, I won't forget ;)

Comment: Hi Stephane, I am just curious if you have any chance to look into this issue. If   my answer is helpful for you, please make it as answer. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Azure Active Directory B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/) to set the Identity providers.

[Sign in with Azure AD account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-setup-oidc-azure-active-directory).

[Sign in with Facebook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-setup-fb-app).

[Sign in with Google](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-setup-goog-app).

[Sign in with SAML provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-setup-sf-app-custom).